# Metro StorageFile Multithreaded File logging

Tags: c#, multithreading, microsoft-metro, storagefile

What is the correct way for handling multithreaded file access to the `StorageFile` object?

After creating a `StorageFile`, I write to it using `FileIO.AppendTextAsync`.

This works, but as soon as multiple threads call `FileIO.AppendTextAsync`, I get Access Denied errors - presumably because a previous call to it, is still running.

How do I deal with this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found the perfect solution, but I have found a workable one.

1. Mark the `StorageFile` with the `volatile` keyword (Significantly reduced errors).
2. Then I refactored some code that was unnecessarily executing from different threads (Now all errors gone).

**NOTE:** Both 1 and 2 implemented together were necessary to achieve the desired result - hence my comment about the solution NOT being perfect.

**UPDATED: For a more correct solution, please see this post:**
[FileIO Multiple Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17000227/metro-app-fileio-writetextasync-multiple-threads)